# Форма отправки сообщения

Tags: php, javascript

Вопрос по обработчику `submit-form-ajax.php`.

Файл load.js выдает ошибку :

> "The problem with sending it, please try again!"

А должен выдавать: "Спасибо за ваше обращение..."

Прошу помочь исправить файл `submit-form-ajax.php`.

1.php :

```
<form>
                   <input type="text" class="req" id="ap-form-name" value="имя...">

                    <input type="text" class="req" id="ap-form-email" value="email...">

                    <textarea class="req" id="ap-form-message">сообщение...</textarea>

                    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
                </p>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset class="ap-thanks">
                <h1>Спасибо за ваше обращение!</h1>
    <p>Мы обязательно обязательно ответим на него.</p>      </fieldset>
         </form>







    <script>    
    jQuery('#ap').data('config',
    {
    "email_form":"info@gmail.com",
    })    
</script>
```

load.js :

```
            function contact_form() {

        ...

                    var _email=book.config['email_form']; 
                    var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message+'&_email='+_email;  

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url:    "php/submit-form-ajax.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        success: function(msg) {

                            // Check to see if the mail was successfully sent
                            if (msg == 'Mail sent') {
                                $("#ap-contact fieldset").hide();
                                $("#ap-contact fieldset.ap-thanks").show();

                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    close_overlay();
                                }, 5000);

                            } else {
                                $('#ap-contact button').fadeIn('fast');
                                alert('The problem with sending it, please try again!');
                            }
                        },

                        error: function(ob,errStr) {
                            alert('Problem with sending.');
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
```

submit-form-ajax.php

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$msg = "
Имя: $name
Email: $email
Текст сообщения: $message
";
$to = "info@gmail.com";
$subject = "Сообщение";
$message = $msg;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers

);
```

Comment: `submit-form-ajax.php` разве возвращает вам в результате `Mail sent`? Я в вашем коде этого не вижу.

Comment: Письма приходят. Да вот проблема во взаимодействии скриптов. В идеале email должен браться из "email_form":"info@gmail.com" (1.php) и в submit-form-ajax.php я его не должен прописывать. Кроме того, скрпт должен выдавать: "Спасибо за ваше обращение...", а выдает Ошибку.

Answer (score 2):

```
...
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
  echo 'Mail sent';
else
  return false;
```

Правда в описании [mail](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php)

> Возвращает TRUE, если письмо было принято для передачи, иначе FALSE.
>
> Важно заметить, что то что письмо было принято для передачи вовсе НЕ
>   означает что оно достигло получателя.

Если считать, что TRUE свидетельствует об отправке письма то нормально.

Comment: Все еще Выдает ошибку "The problem with sending it, please try again!" А должен выдавать: "Спасибо за ваше обращение..."

Comment: Подскажите еще. Как добавить капчу. `<input type="text" class="req" id="capcha" value="2+2=?"> $capcha = $_POST["capcha"]; if ($capcha == '4') {
if(mail($to,$subject,$message))
  echo 'Mail sent';
else
  return false;
  }`

Comment: Попробуйте msg.responseText в js файле в условии